# Beginning on animations

Tags: opengl, c++, animation

I am clueless with regards to animations. I have a simple rendering engine that renders models, sprites, skyboxes and whatnot; but everything is simply static with no animations whatsoever. With my engine written in C++ and OpenGL I will have to learn how to implement animations accordingly; but any OpenGL book or tutorial I look for doesn't explain animations. It's probably one of those topics which being so complex requires its own book or something.

Does anyone know any great resources to explain how I can `programme` animations? I'm not interested in learning how to design them, rather just the technical side of it, you know: bones and all. I would also welcome tips as to the general concept of modern animations in OpenGL. If it also means much, I use assimp as my model loader. Suffice it to say, how does a programmer animate a model to 'run' or 'jump'?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation) on the OpenGL wiki a month ago. It explains the basics of skeletal animations; but I hope it is good enough for what you are trying to do, if not, you can also search `skeletal animation opengl` on google, because there is much more on the opengl wiki about this topic.

Comment: Aren't there any books to assist me with animations?